# Extend global type inside module declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have a third-party library which extend Sting prototype with new method:

```js
String.prototyp.someMethod = () => null;
```

This library should be imported as side-effect library

```js
import 'target-library'
```

I am trying to write declaration file for this module, but keeping clean the global types from this string extension.
For instance, if I do like this

```
// file: types/target-library.d.ts
declare global {
  interface String {
    someMethod: () => null
  }
}
```

than typescript will show this method for all string even if file doesn't import `target-library`.

What I am trying:

```js
// file: types/target-library.d.ts

// Declare string inside module
// Doesn't work at all
declare module 'target-library' {
  interface String {
    someMethod: () => null
  }
}

// Declare global inside module
// Doesn't work as expected: works the same as 
// directly global declaration in the first example
declare module 'target-library' {
  declare global {
    interface String {
      someMethod: () => null
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Those files aren't modules. Unless you've omitted code. Add a blank export. If the file is parsed as a script, then your declarations will be parsed as ambient external modules. If the file is parsed as a module, they will be parsed as module augmentations which is what you want.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I tried the blank export before/after module declaration and this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...typescript will show this method for all string even if file doesn't import target-library.

If the library is extending `String.prototype`, then **any** module importing it anywhere in the project means that all strings in **all** modules have the extension method.

Since that's the case:

1. You probably want to import it from your main entry point module so that it's unambiguously imported.
2. It's correct to do the global type augmentation you showed; it's an accurate reflection of reality.

---

That said, if the library is going to augment `String.pototype` (libraries shouldn't be updating built-ins like that), its own types should say that it does that, rather than your having to do it after-the-fact. It may be worth contributing a PR fixing the module's type information.

Comment: I understand that... but at the same time how typescript can check in buildtime what I imported the module at least once? If i remove all the library imports, typescript will not show errors for code using extended string

Comment: @marvinav - That's why I listed #1 above, so it's umambiguous. You either use the library in your project (with the global augmentation and definite import), or you don't use it in your project and remove both. You can even have both in the same place to avoid a mistake (e.g., `main.ts` or whatever): `import "target-library"; declare global { interface String { someMethod: () => null; } }`